# Cannot convert 'String' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' in initialization

Tags: arduino-ide, string, compilation-errors

Hey all I am trying to convert a string into a uint8_t with the following code:

```
String data = "#255101987";
String tmp1 = data.substring(1, 3);

uint8_t first  = (String)tmp1;
```

I am getting the error of:

> cannot convert 'String' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' in initialization

Any help would be great as I thought adding **(String)** in front of the varible would solve the issue but it hasn't as you can tell.

Comment: Do you want the ASCII value of the character or do you want to parse the string contents as a number?

Comment: I presume from the substring call s/he expects to find 255 in the variable.

Comment: @NickGammon is correct. I am looking for the **255** within the string and needing to convert that to the uint8_t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uint8_t first  = atoi (tmp1.substring(1, 3).c_str ());
```

Or even:

```
String data = "#255101987";
uint8_t first  = atoi (data.substring(1, 3).c_str ());
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for the help, Nick!